# How to create a custom admonition

Tags: docusaurus

Anyone else follow the directions here to make a [custom admonition](https://%20https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/markdown-features/admonitions)?

Error I get:

`[ERROR] ValidationError: "admonitions.extendDefaults" is not allowed`

And if I remove it, it thinks md is code and breaks claiming some of my text is "Import" statements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it is the version of docusaurus, v3 has the custom admonitions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).